# Git log: How to identify (even deleted) topic branch which contains commit?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log

In some cases it would be helpful to see the branch name (even if it deleted)
which contains the matching commits when I grepping the Git history.

#### Problem

For example the output of `git log --grep 'count to G'` in [Unite.vim's
repository](https://github.com/shougo/unite.vim) is:

```
commit 7b173ac0ebeadbb1eec17fd12faa1efdcaaa2bb1
Author: Kevin Ballard <kevin@sb.org>
Date:   Sun Jul 26 17:30:15 2015 -0700

    Support passing a count to G

    The mapping for gg supported a count, but the mapping for G did not. Add
    support, and make it avoid redrawing candidates if a count is provided
    that is within the list of current candidates.
```

The log of the branch of this commit is `git log --oneline --graph
515b01c~..15db364`:

```
*   15db364 Merge pull request #974 from kballard/better-gg-G-mappings
|\
| * 0b39984 Map <C-Home> and <C-End> as well
| * 79daa61 Teach gg to jump to the first candidate instead of the prompt
| * 7b173ac Support passing a count to G
|/
* 515b01c Fix #973 use buflisted()
```

How can I display `pull request #974 from kballard/better-gg-G-mappings` (or
`branch 'name-of-the-branch'`, etc.) in the commit description of `git log
--grep 'count to G`?

#### Own experiences

What I found a possible solution to find out the name of the branch is search
for the SHA in `git log --oneline --graph --all`. It works with exists and
deleted branches too, but I have to track the graph until the merge commit.

Another solution would be `git log --grep 'count to G' --source`: it displays
the ref where the commit belongs to after the SHA, but it gives false
information when the merged branch is deleted (no longer exists).

The last what I found useful is to store the branch name in the commit itself,
but it takes too much space if written to the subject, and becomes useless if
it's in the body, 'cause `--oneline` doesn't shows it). It can be ambiguous if
the branch is renamed after the commit, so I disapproving this as a possible
solution.

#### Question

Is it possible to show the name of the (possible deleted) branch of every
commit in `git log`? Or how can I find out that?

Comment: In Git, a branch is nothing more than a named pointer to a commit. A commit can be in 1 to N branches at any time, and that set of branches can change.

Answer (score 1):

As [Jonathon Reinhart noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343259/git-log-how-to-identify-even-deleted-topic-branch-which-contains-commit/36344886#comment60308470_36343259), the information you want is simply not available in git, and it can change dynamically.  It *is* possible (because the information is static) in some other version control systems, such as Mercurial.  I'll paste another (fairly long, this time) bit from the graph-theory chapter of the book I have been (slowly) working on.  Footnote six is particularly relevant here.  No one needs to read any of it, of course. :-)

That said, `git branch --all --contains <commit>` is basically as close as you can get without also searching through reflogs (if reflogs were retained for deleted branches, that would help with your original question, but (a) they are not and (b) reflogs only last for however long you configure them to last anyway—default 30 days for unreachable commits, 90 days for reachable ones.)  In your particular case, adding and using `--tags` might be more appropriate.  Note that tags are permanent and global, like Mercurial's branches, so in some respects tags would be the way to do this (but git's answer is that you should not do this at all, which is not that great of an answer, really :-) ).

#### Solving the related problem that led you to ask the specific question

If we abandon the question you asked ("identify the branch on which a commit was made") and go back to your original problem statement—which I'll rephrase here as "find whether a commit was merged via a pull request as recorded in a log message"—*that* one git can solve, although you will need to write a bit of script.  In this case what we have is:

- a commit ID `$commit`
- which may (or may not) be "below" a merge commit whose log message is "Merge pull request #[digits] from [string]", on the chain starting from the 2nd parent of that merge commit, up through the point where this 2nd-parent chain rejoins the stream of commits on the 1st-parent chain, probably right at the 1st parent (but it would be nice to allow it to be below that point, and in fact it's significantly *easier* to do that way).

If `$commit` is in fact on such a chain, you want the log message of the merge commit.

To get this we will need to run `git rev-list` to find merges to inspect, and then `git rev-list` again to see if the constraints (commit appears on 2nd-parent side of merge) apply.  The following is not optimized, nor even tested, but shows the idea:

```
git rev-list --merges --all |
while read mhash; do
    msg=$(git log --no-walk --format=%s $mhash)
    case $msg in
    "Merge pull request #"*" from "*) ;;
    *) continue;; # apparently not a pull request
    esac
    if git rev-list ${mhash}^..${mhash}^2 | grep "^${commit}$" >/dev/null; then
        # we found it!
        echo "commit ${commit} is under merge ${mhash}: $msg"
        break
    fi
done
```

This should probably be rewritten to be a bit more robust (in case the pull request merge message doesn't have that exact string format, for instance) and/or clever.  It also assumes that pull request merges are never done as octopus merges (the specific `git rev-list` command using the two parent selectors could be modified to avoid that assumption; it's again meant more for clarity here).

---

## The TL;DR book excerpt - feel free to skip

We are finally ready to address a key difference between Git and Mercurial. Recall the earlier question from Chapter 1 about locating, identifying, and relating commits, and moving commits from one branch to another. In Mercurial, commits are permanently affixed to just one branch. Some of these commits may have in-degree 0, i.e., may be at the leafy ends of branches. Mercurial calls these *heads*.<sup>4</sup> We locate them by their branches; they define the ends of those branches. Since each commit records its parent commit identifier (or two IDs
in the case of a merge), we can use these heads to reach every other commit in the branch (or indeed, in the entire graph). The DAG paths to the other commits give us their relative relationships.

<sup>4</sup>In a normal DAG, we would look at out-degree rather than in-degree: nodes with out-degree 0 are the leaves in our borrowed formal definition 1. Our commit DAG arcs have all been reversed, so we change our viewpoint. The word “leaf” came from the pre-reversal view, but we continue to use it here: Git calls a commit with out-degree 0 a “root commit,” so calling the other ends “leaves” is reasonable enough. Git doesn’t normally bother with a term for them, but for now, we need a concise way to talk about them.

[snip]

Git uses a radically different scheme. Commit nodes *do not* retain branch information. They *do* retain their parent commit identifiers, just as Mercurial’s do, but finding all leaf commits requires trawling through the entire repository.<sup>5</sup> To speed this up, Git provides a general form of *external reference* in a data structure separate from the graph itself. These external references include all of Git’s branches (and Git’s tags, and numerous other forms as well).

Git calls the commit to which a branch name points a *tip* commit. Git’s branch names *do not* have to point to leaf nodes, and *more than one* external reference may point to any given node (including leaf nodes). In effect, each external reference adds one incoming arc to its node. This provides reachability to (some) leaf nodes, but is also the reason a commit may be on more than one branch.<sup>6</sup> These reachable leaf nodes get us to the remaining reachable nodes, just as in Mercurial. Unreachable leaves—nodes with in-degree 0, after adding external references—may be deleted at any time.<sup>7</sup>

The result is that when drawing a Git DAG, we may have multiple branch names pointing to one commit, and we may have commits that (seem to) have *no* names pointing to them. We will say more about this later. For now, let’s revisit Figure 1.6 with Git in mind. We move the branch names to the right, and each branch name points
to the tip of that branch. To emphasize that the *position* of a commit node has little to do with which branches contain it, we may draw them anywhere convenient. The root node is contained within every branch, so there is no reason to prefer the row labeled `master`. To show how one commit can be two different branch tips simultaneously, or a branch tip commit may occur in the midst of a commit chain, we add two more Git branch-names: `A` points to the same commit as `master`, and `B` points to a commit in the middle of the `release-v2 branch`. (These names are meant to be illustrative, rather than immediately useful, though `A` would be a good place to start development of a new feature that is not yet ready to be part of `master`.)

[image: Figure 2.9: Git variant of Figure 1.6.]

[Very big snip here - note that the next bit includes a bit of opinion, and I may end up reworking it a bit in future.  Both stances have merit: Git gains a lot of flexibility with its lightweight, ephemeral branch system, but definitely loses something in the process.]

Some users argue that this proves Mercurial to be superior to Git, because we can always trace individual commits to specific branches. Some users argue that this proves the opposite, for the same reason, noting that a statement like “commit `1417ae2` was made on `hotfix`” has no (or even negative) value several years later. I somewhat regretfully agree with the latter group, but find that this makes Git usage more difficult and error-prone at first, because users have vaguely-defined notions of branches, vague (if any) notions about commit DAGs, and don’t want to have to express subsets all the time (see the next section). Mercurial’s branches are initially just right, but over time, the branch names become very cluttered. Mercurial’s branch- closing feature, which hides the name from normal use, does the trick initially, but the hidden branch name still exists: you must either invent a new (often rather awkward) name or re-open the old branch, and this is where the old branch suddenly has negative value.

---

<sup>5</sup>There are several maintenance git commands that do this, and they take some time to run in larger repositories. Users normally never need to run these on their own, though.

<sup>6</sup>It may be better to think of commits being *contained within* some branches. Git has commands with `--contains` options to see which branches and/or tags contain particular commits.

<sup>7</sup>Git’s garbage collector, or GC, does the deletion. It obeys rules that protect items for a while, until they either get referenced or age out, so “at any time” is not quite true. You can also disable the automatic GC.